# Python interfaces, Design pattern behaviour

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface

- I have a class A with a lot of functionality
- Another class is implementing and extending it. The signature of that class is: `class B(A)`.

What I want now is to split the functionality of class A into a class C and D, depenending on the required mode, lets say mode1 and mode2.

- For mode1: `class B(C)`
- For mode2: `class B(D)`

I'm not so fit with abstract classes, interfaces, design patterns with python and reading through some books did not give me a solution on a per module/class level.
What would be a good solution here? Would I still need class A and make class C and D implementing this?

To give some context: Class A has some functionality for model training (which requires a lot of dependencies) and model inference. I want to be able to run my program rather in training or inference mode. This has the benefit that in case of inference I do not need to load all requirements for training

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, and specifically what you consider a "required mode". In general, you are free to structure *and refactor* your code however you like, so you will definitely not *need* a class A if you don't want to – though of course it raises the question *why* you think still you need it. Can you perhaps [edit] your question to add some details as per [ask]?

Comment: To give some context: Class A has some functionality for model training (which requires a lot of dependencies) and model inference. I want to be able to run my program rather in training or inference mode. This has the benefit that in case of inference I do not need to load all requirements for training.